# Triggered Sends - EventAPI Key

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

I have created a triggered send as per the requirement. Now the Front-end developer is asking me for the EventAPI key for the Triggered send that I created. I share the external key of the triggered send. But he says that is not the one he wants. he wants eventapi key of the triggered send. 
Can anyone let me know what is he asking exactly for.

Comment: Event api key sounds like he is trying to use journey builder instead of triggered sends.

Comment: Yes as @Tyler said Event Key is used for events in JB, for triggered sends you would use the RequestID, which is returned in the success envelope once the call is made.  If this is for JB then, the same would be true of eventID inside of the returned success envelope when entering journey. Otherwise, you could use  the Journey History endpoint (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/275887/journey-builder-api-to-extract-total-populations/276440#276440) to try and grab it.

Comment: I am using Triggered Sends. Not journey builder. our front end developer was mentioning for API Event key

Comment: Triggered Sends do not have EventKey - you would use RequestID for those to gather Instance related data.

Comment: Also forgot to note that RecipientSendId is also returned via REST API calls - which is used instead for Instance related data.

Answer (score 1):

> Interactions have a unique External Key value that is used by the API
>   calls to initiate the interaction.

Whether you are using SOAP or REST, you will need the ExternalKey of the Triggered Send to send an email:

[image]

Here's an example SOAP body:

```
<soapenv:Body>
    <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Objects xsi:type="TriggeredSend">
            <Client>
                <ID>INSERT MID OF BU</ID>
            </Client>
            <TriggeredSendDefinition>
                <CustomerKey>INSERT TRIGGERED SEND KEY</CustomerKey>
            </TriggeredSendDefinition>
            <Subscribers>
                <SubscriberKey>INSERT SUBSCRIBER KEY</SubscriberKey>
                <EmailAddress>INSERT SUBSCRIBER EMIAL ADDRESS</EmailAddress>
            </Subscribers>
        </Objects>
    </CreateRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
```

and for REST API calls, you would include the key in the endpoint path:

```
https://xxxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:INSERT TRIGGERED SEND KEY/send
```

Here's the official documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/triggered_email_scenario_guide_for_developers.htm